# Filter rows out with specific value for each sample column

Tags: r, dplyr

Keep rows (Obs) which Obs value is over the threshold value of the sample IN AT LEAST THREE SAMPLES. Remove rows which have 2 or less.

ie.

- Obs 1 has only S5 over the threshold so would be filteresd out;
- Obs2 has 4 and Obs 3 has 3 so they would remain in the df.

.

```
df <- data.frame(column=c("threshold", "Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3"), S1 = c(1.7,1.4,1.9,1.3), S2= c(0.9,0.8,2,1), S3=c(2.5,2.4,2.1,0.5), S4=c(0.4,0.5,0.6,0.9), S5=c(1.2,1.4,1.3,1.6))
 df

    column      S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
    threshold  1.7 0.9 2.5 0.4 1.2 
    Obs1       1.4 0.8 2.4 0.5 1.4 
    Obs2       1.9 2.0 2.1 0.6 1.3
    Obs3       1.3 1.0 0.5 0.9 1.6
```

Desired output:

```
column      S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
 
Obs2       1.9 2.0 2.1 0.6 1.3
Obs3       1.3 1.0 0.5 0.9 1.6
```

I do not know how to code it but I wonder if using some logic like this:

```
logic <- if df (S1-5)>= threshold value then =1; if df (S1-5) < threhold then = 0 

library(dplyr)
logic  %>% rowwise %%
    filter(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric))) >= 3) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: The first row of df called  "threshold"includes the threshold value for each column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using `rowwise` with `c_across`, just `slice` the rows without the 'threshold' row and then do the comparison `>` with the corresponding `slice`d dataset with 'threshold' rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    slice(-1) %>% 
    rowwise %>%
    filter(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)) 
                > 
                  (df %>% 
                      slice(1) %>%
                   select(-1))) >=3) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  column    S1    S2    S3    S4    S5
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Obs2     1.9     2   2.1   0.6   1.3
#2 Obs3     1.3     1   0.5   0.9   1.6
```

If there are other character columns as well, we can change the `select` for subset data

```
df  %>% 
   slice(-1) %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   filter(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)) > df %>%
             slice(1) %>%
             select(where(is.numeric))) >=3)
```

---

Or another option with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
i1 <- map(df %>%
              select(where(is.numeric)),  ~ .x[-1] >  first(.x)) %>% 
        reduce(`+`) %>% 
        is_greater_than(2)
df %>% 
     slice(-1) %>% 
     filter(i1)
```

---

Or using `base R` with `rowSums`

```
df[-1,][rowSums(df[-1, -1] > df[1, -1][col(df[-1, -1])]) >=3,]
#  column  S1 S2  S3  S4  S5
#3   Obs2 1.9  2 2.1 0.6 1.3
#4   Obs3 1.3  1 0.5 0.9 1.6
```

Comment: Thanks, they all work, but I would like to understand them as well. For option (1- dplyr) what function stablishes the "greater than theshold"?; for option (2-map) does *is_greater_than(2)* means greater to value in row 2? for (3-base) where are you saying "give a value of 1 if greater than threshold?. Sorry many questions but I'd like to learn! Thanks @akrun

Comment: @Ecg For option 1, we are subsetting the rows first because it is rowwise.  So, the row with threshold row data is passed directly within to do a corresponding `>` with `c_across` i.e. (`df %>% 
                      slice(1) %>%
                   select(-1))` and the threshold is done with `>=3`.  In the second case, we are looping over the numeric columns with `map`, subset the first element and do a comparison with the rest, create an index ('i1') and use that to subset the rows.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, with read carefully and will try to understand. !

Comment: I find the code with my data does not work because my "threshold values" are decimal, whereas the other values are not. SO the code would not work with something like this: < df1 <- data.frame(column=c("threshold", "Obs1", "Obs2", "Obs3"), S1 = c(1.7,1,2,2), S2= c(1.3,0,0,3), S3=c(0.5,1,1,2), S4=c(1.2,1,2,2), S5=c(1.6,3,1,2)) > could I cancel the fact that the threshold values are decimal?

Comment: @Ecg Not clear when you say it is not working.  I tried your example and it is working for me

Comment: I see... The thing is that here I am giving you a reproducible example, which I see when creating the df columns c() it gives a decimal value to everything ) ie 2 gets converted to 2.0 and it is fine. On my dataset I have natural numbers and threshold number as decimals, so it generates an output with no data. Maybe making the whole database decimal if numeric?

Comment: @Ecg I think you are concerned with the `tibble` printing format.  It is format issue and not the actual value issue.  THe values will have the decimals.  You can check by converting to `data.frame` from `tibble`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224445/discussion-between-ecg-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
If you work with columns which are character, you need to make sure the columns with the values are numeric, if not, transform them

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

and then, this should work

```
df2 <- df %>% slice(-1) %>% rowwise %>% filter(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)) > (df %>%slice(1))) >=3)
```